# How to Compare DateTime Values

Tags: c#, string, datetime, windows-phone-8

I am saving my app's first launch date plus three days from now as a string value. I am then attempting to perform a string comparison when the MainPage is NavigatedTo to compare these string values. To note, this will have to work in any culture set, although from what I understand here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now(v=vs.110).aspx `DateTime.Now` will always get the local values for a correct comparison. Currently I am getting a `TargetInvocationException` when doing this, and not sure how to solve the issue

Store this when the app is first launched into a custom `Settings` class which will save the string value

```
Settings.FutureDate.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString();
```

Check this in the app page when loaded

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime futureDate = DateTime.Parse(Settings.FutueDate.Value); 

//If three days has passed, notify user
if (currentDate >= DateTime.Parse(Settings.FutureDate.Value)) //TargetInvocationException error occurs here
{
    MessageBox.Show("Three days has passed.");
}
```

EDIT

When checking the `currentDate` and `Settings.FutureDate.Value` values from above before the comparison, I see the following.

```
currentDate = {8/13/2014 3:07:17 PM}
futureDate = {8/16/2014 3:07:09 PM}
```

Comment: What *is* `Settings.FutureDate.Value` when you try to parse it?

Comment: Can you post what Settings.FutureDate is ? I suspect that it is a Nullable<string> but not 100% sure

Comment: @BlueTrin A Nullable<string> would just be a string

Comment: I do first initialize `Settings.FutureDate.Value` as null but as soon as the app is launched for the first time its updated to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString()` and I can confirm that when hovering my cursor over the value.

Comment: Matthew print the value here in your question and try to split the DateTime.Parse on another line. I don't think that the comparison itself is causing an error.

Comment: I have posted an edit of what I see when checking `currentDate` and `futureDate` `DateTime` values before the comparison.

Comment: Matthew, what is the type of `Settings.FutureDate` ? Also replace `if (currentDate >= DateTime.Parse(Settings.FutureDate.Value))` with `if (currentDate >= futureDate)`

Comment: I will make that update, and `Settings.FutureDate.Value` returns a string of the original DateTime set here `Settings.FutureDate.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should store the date itself as a `DateTime` instead of using a string, if `Settings.FutureDate` is a `Nullable<DateTime>` then:

```
Settings.FutureDate= DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
```

Then your code becomes:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

if (Settings.FutureDate)
{
    //If three days has passed, notify user
    if (currentDate >= Settings.FutureDate.Value) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Three days has passed.");
    }
}
```

There is no reason to store the string rather than the DateTime itself as you can conveniently obtain the string at any time. This is likely to get rid of your error if it was due to creating the `DateTime` from a `string`.

Please can you print the value of the string `FutureDate.Value` ? Also try to split your code in the following manner and tell us what line causes the error:

```
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;

DateTime settingsDate = DateTime.Parse(Settings.FutureDate.Value);
if (currentDate >= settingsDate) 
{        //If three days has passed, notify user
    if (currentDate >= Settings.FutureDate.Value) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Three days has passed.");
    }
}
```

I suspect the error will happen on the `DateTime.Parse`. To know why we need you to print the value of `Settings.FutureDate.Value`.

EDIT1:
I saw your string, you did not say the type of `Settings.FutureDate`. However this works for me in a fresh new project, please note the `ParseExact` where I provide the exact format of the string to parse.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    class Settings
    {


        public static string FutureDate { get; set; }

    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Settings.FutureDate = "8/16/2014 3:07:09 PM";
        }



        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            DateTime futureDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Settings.FutureDate, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", provider);

            if (currentDate >= futureDate) //TargetInvocationException error occurs here
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Three days has passed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not actually have to use `ParseExact` it turns out I just had to declare `currentDate` and `futureDate` individually as type `DateTime and then compare using `currentDate >= futureDate` as opposed to `currentDate >= DateTime.Parse(Settings.FutureDate.Value)` in my original post. Not sure why. Also since my app will be in different languages I stuck with `Parse`.

Comment: It makes sense to use Parse. I wish I could see your code because there must be a reason for the exception, but because I cannot see the class implementation of FutureDate and .Value I cannot see what is wrong. Anyway I am glad it works for you now.